# Why Math.sin`1` works and Math.sin'1' not

Tags: javascript, syntax, tags

If I enter this expression in the browser console (with grave accent):

```js
Math.sin`1`
```

It will return:

```js
0.8414709848078965
```

But if I enter this expression (with single quote):

```js
Math.sin'1'
```

It will throw this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Why does this error happen?

Comment: ``tag`template literal`︁`` is [specifically part of the template literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates). It doesn’t work for other string literals.

Comment: Thanks you! There was no link to tags from template string section in my manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` tag`template literal` `` is [specifically part of the template literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates). It doesn’t work for other string literals.

Answer (score 2):

That's what's called a [tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
fn`string`
```

assuming `fn` is a function, will simply result in `fn` being called with `string` as the first argument.

Tagged template literal functions are more useful when you have `${ .. }` replacements to make. From the MDN example:

```js
var person = 'Mike';
var age = 28;

function myTag(strings, personExp, ageExp) {
  var str0 = strings[0]; // "that "
  var str1 = strings[1]; // " is a "
  return str0 + personExp + str1 + (
    ageExp > 99
    ? 'centenarian'
    : 'youngster'
  );
}

console.log(myTag`that ${ person } is a ${ age }`);
```